# Laravel 5.3: How-to mark navigation menu as active, when the request matches the URL (with language)

Tags: laravel-5, locale, multilingual

I want to mark a navigation menu as "active", when the URL matches the request.

This is working fine:

```
    <div class="sidebar">
            <ul class="sidebar-menu">
                    <li {{{ (Request::is('en/dashboard') ? 'class=active' : '') }}}>
                            <a href="/{{ App::getLocale() }}/dashboard">
                                    <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>{{ trans('sidebar.dashboard') }}</span>
                            </a>
                    </li>

                    <li {{{ (Request::is('en/settings') ? 'class=active' : '') }}}>
                            <a href="/{{ App::getLocale() }}/settings">
                                    <i class="fa fa-gears"></i> <span>{{ trans('sidebar.settings') }}</span>
                            </a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

Unfortunately, it's only working and marking the navigation menu, when the URL uses the language code "en". But how can I replace the static string "en" with something more dynamic?

I've already tried to solve this problem by using this code, but it doesn't work:

```
    <li {{{ (Request::is('{{ App::getLocale() }}/dashboard') ? 'class=active' : '') }}}>
```

What's the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm now using this solution, which works very well and keeps the blade clean.

First of all, give each of your routes a unique name in your `routes/web.php`:

```
    <?php

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Web Routes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
    | routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
    | contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
    |
    */

    Route::get('/admin/dashboard', 'DashboardController@getAll')->name('dashboard');
    Route::get('/admin/maintenances', 'MaintenanceController@get')->name('maintenances-overview');
    Route::get('/admin/users', 'UserController@getUsers')->name('users-overview');
```

In your navigation blade (eg. `resources/views/layouts/admin/navbar.blade.php`), you can now simply reference to these names:

```
    <li class="{{ Route::currentRouteName() == 'dashboard' ? 'active' : '' }}">
        <a href="{{ route('dashboard') }}">Dashboard</a>
    </li>

    <li class="{{ Route::currentRouteName() == 'maintenances-overview' ? 'active' : '' }}">
        <a href="{{ route('maintenances-overview') }}">Maintenances</a>
    </li>

    <li class="{{ Route::currentRouteName() == 'users-overview' ? 'active' : '' }}">
        <a href="{{ route('users-overview') }}">Users</a>
    </li>
```

This solution is also very helpful, when you've a multi-language site, because you don't have to use regular expressions to determine, if it's now a matching URL or not. You also can edit and update your route URLs to whatever you want to without the need to update all your blades, just because the URL got changed. The `route()` function returns autom. the updated URL and the `Route::currentRouteName()` function does always return the set name of your route. :)

Just as hint for multi-language sites: You can simply replace the static text `Users` with a language variable:

```
    <li class="{{ Route::currentRouteName() == 'users-overview' ? 'active' : '' }}">
        <a href="{{ route('users-overview') }}">@lang('layouts/admin/navbar.users')</a>
    </li>
```

For further information regarding localization, please take a look at the [laravel.com localization documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/localization)

Comment: yes this is good thing but i think not better than solution Tim Lewis show as first answer because think about you click on one of articles in articles list and the route name is articles.show and <li> tag is active when name of that is articles.index for list of articles and now its make problem for article item

Answer (score 2):

Usually, I have a layout with these nav items extended by the current view, so something like:

```
<li><a href="{{ url("home") }}>Home</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ url("about") }}>About</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ url("contact") }}>Contact</a></li>
```

Then my routes:

```
Route::get("/home", "BasicController@getHome");
```

Then in my controller:

```
public function getHome(){
    return view("home")->with(["page" => "home"]);
}
```

Now that my view `home.blade.php` has a `$page` being passed to it, and since it extends the `.blade` file with the nav section (usually `@extends("layouts.master")` or something) you can access and check the `$page` variable against these nav items:

```
<li class="{{ $page == "home" ? "active" : "" }}><a href="{{ url("/home") }}>Home</a></li>
```

This way you don't have to worry about matching routes in multiple languages to their active page. The only downside is that you need to include a `->with(["page" => "whatever"])` in each of your controllers that returns a view that extends that nav layout. There may be an easier way to accomplish that, but this should give you a start.

Comment: And how do you detect the language and change the navigation menu like "Settings" to the German version "Einstellungen" for example?

Comment: That's handled using `trans()`, with folders for `en`, `fr`, ect etc (not sure what the language code for German is), and you would then have the link look like this: `<li class="{{ $page == "home" ? "active" : "" }}><a href="{{ url("/home") }}>{{ trans("urls.home") }}</a></li>`. `urls` would be a file in each of the `resources/lang` folders that would contain an array of all the applicable translations. So for English: `return [ "settings" => "Settings" ];` and in German `return ["settings" => "Einstellungen"];`

Comment: You'll have to read the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/localization to get a better handle on localization

Answer (score 0):

It simple.Just do the following in your file that contains your header or navbar and the links:

```
<li class="{{ (Request::path()=='nameofyourfile' ? 'active' : '') }}">
 <a href="{{ route('nameofyourfile') }}">
                        <span class="icon fa fa-building-o" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="title">nameofyourfile</span>
                                                </a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just drop this little function code in your helpers class

```
function is_current_route($route){
    return Route::currentRouteName() == $route ? 'class=active' : '';
}
```

And use it like this in your views

```
<li {{is_current_route('your-route-name-here')}}>
<a href="{{ url("/home") }}>Home</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Why should I add the function `Route::currentRouteName()` to a helper class, when you can already use it out-of-the-box in the view? Example: `<li class="{{ Route::currentRouteName() == 'dashboard' ? 'active' : '' }}">`. Also see solution at the top.

Comment: is to make ur code cleaner and not to repeat your self every time

Comment: If I repeat `is_current_route('your-route-name-here')` or `Route::currentRouteName() == 'users-overview' ? 'active' : ''` won't change a lot, but adding this extra function wastes my time in my opinion. Not sure, how other users see this, but that's my opinion regarding this.

Comment: oh that great then